# PHP Match All Character in New Line with Regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, preg-replace-callback

I want to match any character after `[nextpage]` bbcode but the below bbcode does not match texts that follow when i make a break line.

```
$string="[nextpage] This is how i decided to make a living with my laptop.
This doesn't prevent me from doing some chores,

I get many people who visits me on a daily basis.

[nextpage] This is the second method which i think should be considered before taking any steps.

That way does not stop your from excelling. I rest my case.";

$pattern="/\[nextpage\]([^\r\n]*)(\n|\r\n?|$)/is";
preg_match_all($pattern,$string,$matches);
$totalpages=count($matches[0]);
$string = preg_replace_callback("$pattern", function ($submatch) use($totalpages) { 
$textonthispage=$submatch[1];
return "<li> $textonthispage";
}, $string);
echo $string;
```

This only returns the texts in the first line.

```
<li> This is how i decided to make a living with my laptop.

<li> This is the second method which i think should be considered before taking any steps.
```

Expected result;

```
<li> This is how i decided to make a living with my laptop.
This doesn't prevent me from doing some chores,

I get many people who visits me on a daily basis.

<li> This is the second method which i think should be considered before taking any steps.

That way does not stop your from excelling. I rest my case.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may search using this  regex:

```
\[nextpage]\h*(?s)(.+?)(?=\[nextpage]|\z)
```

Replace by:

```
<li>$1
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TfRxmD/1)

**PHP Code:**

```
$re = '/\[nextpage]\h*(?s)(.+?)(?=\[nextpage]|\z)/';
$result = preg_replace($re, '<li>$1', $str);
```

[Code Demo](https://eval.in/848648)

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
\[nextpage]         # match literal text "[nextpage]"
\h*                 # match 0+ horizontal whitespaces
(?s)(.+?)           # match 1+ any characters including newlines
(?=\[nextpage]|\z)  # lookahead to assert that we have another "[nextpage]" or end of text
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed string you should not regex. Regex is expensive, a simple str_replace does the trick as well:

```
$result = str_replace("[nextpage]", "<li>", $str);
```

---

If you want it as proper HTML, you need a close tag as well:

```
$result = str_replace("[nextpage]", "</li><li>", $string);
$result = substr($result, 5, strlen($result)).'</li>'; // remove the start </li>

echo $result;
```